# Why does this mismatch in lexical scoping occur?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, lexical-scope

This issue occurs in both Node 6.9.4 and 7.0.0, and I cannot figure out why. I haven't tested in other versions. See comments in Node.js program below:

```
const express = require('express');
const adaro = require('adaro');

const app = express();

const tabs = require('./config/tabs.json');
const config = require('./config/locals.js');

function getLocals(name) {
  const modifiedTabs = config.tabs.map(tab => {
    return Object.assign(tab, {active: tab.name === name});
  });

  return Object.assign({tab: name}, config, {tabs: modifiedTabs});
}

app.engine('dust', adaro.dust());
app.set('view engine', 'dust');
app.set('x-powered-by', false);

app.use(express.static('static'));

tabs.map(tab => tab.name).forEach(name => {
  const locals = getLocals(name);
  const tab = locals.tabs.find(tab => tab.active);

  // these are always true
  console.log(tab === locals.tabs.find(tab => tab.active));

  function callback(req, res) {
    // const locals = getLocals(name);
    // this should be true, but is false unless the line above is commented in
    console.log(tab === locals.tabs.find(tab => tab.active));
    res.render('main', locals);
  }

  if (tab.url !== '/' + tab.id) {
    app.get(tab.url, callback);
  }

  app.get('/' + tab.id, callback);
});

app.all('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendStatus(404);
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000);
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Log out `locals` and `getLocals(name)` at the line you have commented out. My guess is they will be different because you are mutating an object somewhere and not realizing it.

Comment: *facepalm* I just found the mutation: `Object.assign(tab, {active: tab.name === name})` line 11...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. In `getLocals()`, I'm executing

```
const modifiedTabs = config.tabs.map(tab => {
  return Object.assign(tab, {active: tab.name === name});
});
```

The `Object.assign(tab, ...)` overwrites the existing `tab` object each time it's called, leaving only the last assignments to each tab. So all the views show the last tab in the array as active, since all their `active` properties have been overwritten with those of the last tab's configuration.

The solution was to switch the arguments to `Object.assign()` so that the returned object was created rather than overwritten:

```
return Object.assign({active: tab.name === name}, tab);
```